# calling a struct but its not showing in swiftui

Tags: swiftui

i have this class

```
class AppSetting: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showUserMenu = false
    @Published var edges = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top
    @Published var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}
```

and two structs

```
struct HeaderBar : View {
    @ObservedObject private var appSetting = AppSetting()
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            HStack{
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation(.spring()){appSetting.showUserMenu.toggle()}
                    print("menu button clicked.")
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3")                        
                })                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)                
                })
            }            
            Text("Home")
        }
        .padding(.top, appSetting.edges)
    }
}
```

and this

```
struct LeftMenu : View {
@ObservedObject private var appSetting = AppSetting()
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation(.spring()){appSetting.showUserMenu.toggle()}
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                    })
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                }
                .padding(.top, appSetting.edges)
                HStack(spacing: 15){
                    Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                }
                // Menu Buttons...
                VStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
                    ForEach(studentMenuData.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                        let tmpArray = key.components(separatedBy: " ")
                        MenuButtons(image: "\(tmpArray[1])", title: "\(studentMenuData[key]!)", pageValue: Int(tmpArray[0]) ?? 0)
                    }
                })
            }
            .frame(width: appSetting.width - 50)
            .offset(x: appSetting.showUserMenu ? 0 : -400 ) // hide menu
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(appSetting.showUserMenu ? 0.3 : 0))
    }
}
```

now when i call these functions from a view

```
struct StudentProfileView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var appSetting = AppSetting()
    @State var selectedIndex = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                HeaderBar()
                // view
                VStack {
                    Image("Icon")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                    
                    Text("Student Name")                   
                }
                .padding(.top)                
            }
            LeftMenu()            
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

the menu is not showing but when i copy the struct's code directly on uiprofile view, then its working, i don't want to copy the same code on all screens.

please help me to know when i am doing wrong and how i can make it right.

Comment: Is the target selected in the File Inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `LeftMenu` view you're creating a new instance of `AppSetting` class instead of passing it from `StudentProfileView`.

That is causing `LeftMenu` from not getting the change (updates) made your the `AppSetting` which is in your `StudentProfileView`

Fo fix this, change your `LeftMenu` View, change

```
@ObservedObject private var appSetting = AppSetting()
```

to

```
@ObservedObject var appSetting: AppSetting
```

and then in your `StudentProfileView` change

```
LeftMenu()
```

to

```
LeftMenu(appSetting: appSetting)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, it was not working because appSetting was Private, right ?

Comment: @KodeLerner it's not really because it's private. It's because it was a different instance of `AppSetting`. Any time you do `AppSetting()` you're making a *new version* of that object. It needs to be shared/passed through your view hierarchy with the *same version*.